# How to hide grub menu in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.04

I have two operating systems: Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. I want to hide grub menu. I'm using grub 2.02~beta2-9. I tried following combinations of `/etc/default/grub`:

1. ```
   \#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1  
   \#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true  
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
   ```

   grub menu is visible for 10 seconds (if timeout is set for value larger than 0 it is displayed correctly: `GRUB_TIMEOUT=5` - 5 seconds delay)
2. ```
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1  
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true  
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
   ```

   grub menu is visible, I also tried `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=false` and setting both `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` to zero and non-zero values
3. ```
   \#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1  
   \#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true  
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=1  
   GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
   ```

   grub menu is visible for 1 second, tried also `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown` with the same result, if `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is set to 0, 10 seconds delay

After each change I type `update-grub` and restart computer to see the results.

According to GRUB documentation found in `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'` second way is deprecated. The right way is the third one - by using `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE`, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It's probably some kind of a bug.

Comment: A lot of times, the recipes you find online don't work just right. In that case, consult the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html

Comment: That's what I've done in the first place. It doesn't work as specified in documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally if you had only one OS running the option `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` would work.
If GRUB 2's `os-prober` identifies additional operating systems while running the `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` script the hidden menu timeout feature is disabled by conditional statements. This also disables the ability to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to display the menu during boot. Users with multiple operating systems wishing to hide the menu can find script edits on various forums which will allow them to add a hidden timeout feature to the boot sequence.

Check [this answer](/q/117525) if it helps you.

Comment: On your link I found quick solution that permanently hides grub menu:
`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0`
Although it would be better if I could just show GRUB when pressing SHIFT (in previous ubuntu version I could adjust it by manipulating GRUB_TIMEOUT and GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT), but it is still the best solution that doesn't require writing custom scripts.

Answer (score 8):

I have found a very quick solution, but I haven't looked at the consequences yet.

In your os_prober script for update-grub there are some lines to by-pass the timeout you set and to force displaying a boot menu if an other os has been found. You can easily disable this by setting the "quick_boot" variable to 0.

- In `/etc/grub.d/30_os_prober` at the beginning of the file change

  `quick_boot="1"` to `quick_boot="0"`
- Then run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 2):

I tried editing `30_os_prober`, but it turned out that the name has been changed to `10_os_prober`.

Other than that the solution offered above by [Motsah](https://askubuntu.com/users/287414/motsah) works perfectly for me.

I now have:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"   
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="1"   
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"    
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
```

in my `/etc/default/grub`

Changing the hidden timeout to a higher setting doesn't seem to do a thing. Having 0 
makes entering the menu impossible.

Copied from above, changing to 10_os_prober to make this complete:

In `/etc/grub.d/10_os_prober` 
change

```
quick_boot="1"
```

to

```
quick_boot="0"
```

in the beginning of the file.

Run:

```
sudo update-grub
```