# Grub loader always takes 10 seconds

Tags: 14.04, grub2, bootloader, grub-efi, refind

The default grub loader is always runing 10 second countdown before launching Ubuntu 14.04.

This is how it looks in etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

The RECORDFAIL line was added in an atempt to fix this problem. It did not help.

After making any change `sudo update-grub` is executed.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have enabled `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET`, but you haven't specified the timeout length of it (`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`is commented). This is why it is reverting back to 10 seconds.

Because `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` has it's own timeout length config line, you need to uncomment the line making the timeout for it equal to 0.

Having `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`, [will hide the GRUB menu on boot](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/ubuntu-1404-hide-grub-menu/), which I assume is what you were attempting by making `GRUB_TIMEOUT` equal to 0.

Comment: Thank you, [this answer also helped](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469347/how-to-hide-grub-menu-in-ubuntu-14-04) to hide the boot menu permanently since GRUB_TIMEOUT_QUIET doesn't work if there is another OS installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can install boot-repair. And set the timeout through advanced settings in boot-repair.

Click on the Advanced option on boot-repair
[image: Boot-repair starting menu]

Now change the Unhide boot menu : 10 seconds to whatever time you want
[image: Advanced boot-repair]

And click apply. If you wanted to install boot-repair checkout this link [Installing Boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598543/problem-in-dual-boot/598555#598555)