# Make grub not show at all during boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 15.04

I have a PC with Windows 7 and Ubuntu.
Is there a way to make grub not show at all and boot directly into the default os, and when I want I can press a key or something and choose to boot into something else.
[This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10997838/) is my grub file.
I have tried many options like hidden timeout , timeout style ,etc but nothing works

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader for the answer to how to make GRUB default to boot Windows,

Answer (score 5):

First of all, please check this question to see how Windows can be set as the default for booting: [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

To hide grub unless a button is pressed, you need to configure grub to do so:

- Press `Alt+F2`, type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` press Enter and enter your password.
- Set the options like following:

  ```
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=6
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
  ```
- Save the file by pressing `CTRL+s`.
- Then to activate the changes you made, run this command and enter your user password when prompted:

  ```
  $ sudo update-grub2
  ```

Now if you reboot, grub menu should't display unless you don't press a button in 6 seconds (which is set by `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` configuration).

Another option is this:

Set both `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` as `0` and grub menu won't be displayed unless you press shift button while booting.

For more information about grub configuration, you can check this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring_GRUB_2

Comment: can i make it a specific button?

Comment: I updated my answer, please see the 'Another option' part.

Comment: i tried the 'another option' by setting `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`          `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`      and          `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`  but the grub menu was displayed and timeout was 10 seconds. (i updated grub)

Comment: I am not using the configuration I suggested so I can't test, can you please check this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/469347/how-to-hide-grub-menu-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: both your above answers don't seem to work for me